# Extremely fussy and refusing to sleep 12-week-old

Tags: newborn, breastfeeding, naps

My 12-week-old daughter has practically refused to nap during last two days. She is unusually agitated and wants to suck almost all the time. Is something wrong with her?

Comment: It is good to have some books (or any other source for that matter) that give you insight in those spurts. When you understand what is going on, it assures you that all is well. This gives you better perspective and ease of mind which results in (slightly) better care of your child as well, as the agitation/worries on your side lessen. At least, that is how I experience things.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk notice that I posted both answer and question. I found a possible answer, but found it difficult to google. Hopefully my answer here will make it easier for other people.

Answer (score 3):

11-13 weeks is when a growth spurt may take place. 11-13 weeks is also the time when yet another wonder week may occur.

The slightly-fussier period of a wonder week may last for a few weeks.

The extremely-fussy, constantly sucking no-sleep growth spurt period usually lasts only 2 or 3 days.

If you are really worried or seeing another worrysome symptom, don't hesitate to consult your pediatrician.

Comment: All of this. The wonder week around this time is shorter (I think usually half a week) and the growth spurt up to 5 days. It's the next wonder week that can go on for up to 6 weeks.